# VB.NET typewriter effect

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i want to make typewriter effect like:

http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/9775/screenshot0002mm2.gif

```
dim s as string = "123"
label1.text = s.substring(0,1)
WAIT
label1.text = s.substring(0,2)
WAIT
label1.text = s.substring(0,3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public str As String
Public count As Integer
```

Form1_Load:

```
 Label1.Text = ""
 count = 1
 str = ":D test 12345678910"
 Timer1.Enabled = True
```

timer_tick:

```
If Label1.Text.Length = str.Length Then
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Exit Sub
End If
Label1.Text = str.Substring(0, count)
count = count + 1
```

just use timer :)

Comment: error: 'Label1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: add label control to youre form

Answer (score 0):

declare timer:

For each character in string

console.writeline(character)

//or you can write this to textbox. Textbox.text= Textbox.text & character

add time (you can set the delay between each character)

end for